# H3lp High School Student With Python Loop

Tags: python, loops

This is supposed to be code for a system in a store that loops again and again if someone wants to buy something else. Please help.

```
menu=["apple","water","juice"]
apple=50
water=80
juice=100


money=int(input("How much money in pennies do you have?"))
if money>=100:
  print("We have the following items you can buy: apple, water, juice")
elif money>=80 and money<=100:
  print("We have the following items you can buy: apple, water")
elif money>=50 and money<=80:
  print("We have the following item you can buy: apple")
else:
  print("Sorry, you can't buy anything.")


buy=input("What do you want to buy?")
if buy=="apple":
  print("You have",money-50)
elif buy=="water":
  print("You have",money-80)
else:
  print("You have",money-100)

other=(input("Do you want to buy anything else?"))
if other=="yes":
  while x=0:
  print(x)
    continue
elif other=="no":
  x+1
else:
  print("Error")
```

The last part doesn't work- can someone fix it so it does? This is Python 3- thanks.

Comment: try removing the outer braces: `other=input("Do you want to buy anything else?")`

Comment: You want to put the parts where you ask for input in a loop (basically the whole thing except where you declare the variables).

Comment: the while is pretty confusing for me - i'd propose you put the whole buying cycle into a `while True` and `break` it when the answer to `other` is something other than "yes".

Comment: We are generally not fond of fixing someone's homework here. At least give some more motivation and explanation. What needs to happen, what is not happening as you like, how you tried to debug, and so on. (Also, `H3lp` isn't really working for your cause either. `;-)`)

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed & loop optimized -

the problem you encountered was the extra brackets `()` around your input-function.

the loop is now optimized because your whole buying cycle is now inside this `while True:` loop. it will be repeated again and again until the user inputs something different then "yes" at the other question.

```
while True: 
    menu=["apple","water","juice"]
    apple=50
    water=80
    juice=100


    money=int(input("How much money in pennies do you have?"))
    if money>=100:
        print("We have the following items you can buy: apple, water, juice")
    elif money>=80 and money<=100:
        print("We have the following items you can buy: apple, water")
    elif money>=50 and money<=80:
        print("We have the following item you can buy: apple")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you can't buy anything.")


    buy=input("What do you want to buy?")
    if buy=="apple":
        print("You have",money-50)
    elif buy=="water":
        print("You have",money-80)
    else:
        print("You have",money-100)

    other=input("Do you want to buy anything else?")
    if other=="yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Since this is clearly a student asking for a fix, it is suitable to give an explanation about what went wrong in their original code, what you fixed, and how you _optimized_.

Answer (score 0):

```
other=(input("Do you want to buy anything else?"))
if other=="yes":
   while x=0:        <-- should use x==0, but x is not declared
   print(x)          <-- wrong indentation
       continue
elif other=="no":
    x+1              <-- even if x was declared, this only sum and nothing 
else:                    more (nothing changes in your program)
    print("Error")
```

This last part basically does nothing useful even if it worked. I suggest you to use the code posted in the other answer.